# Enviando uma Lista de dados por E-mail - ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa noite, estou fazendo uma aplicação web para faculdade onde preciso enviar uma lista de dados (alimentos) provenientes de uma cotação. Ou seja, o usuário seleciona os itens que irá cotar e após isso envia via e-mail para o email desejado, a questão é: O envio do e-mail está sendo feito normalmente, o problema é que quando chega no meu e-mail a Lista de alimentos, chega apenas a seguinte informação:

De: airtonteste@gmail.com.br

Para: airtonteste@gmail.com.br

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjetoCotacao2.Models.Alimento]

Agradecemos o contato!

Na hora de debugar, vejo que os itens estão retornando corretamente mas não é enviado no e-mail... pensei em fazer um foreach dentro do corpo do email mas não obtive sucesso, segue o método no controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EnviarEmail(UsuarioCliente cotacao)
    {

        String email = cotacao.Email_Cliente;
        String assunto = "ASSUNTO EMAIL";

        List<Alimento> a = new List<Alimento>();
        a = AlimentoDAO.RetornarAlimentos();



        WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
        WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
        WebMail.UserName = "airtonteste@gmail.com";
        WebMail.Password = "senha";
        WebMail.From = "airtonteste@gmail.com";


        try
        {
            WebMail.Send(to: email,
                from: "airtonteste@gmail.com"",
                   subject: assunto,
                   body: a +
                   "<p> Agradecemos o contato!</p>"
                   );
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "UsuarioCliente");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "UsuarioCliente");
        }
    }
```

A camada DAO:

```
        public static List<Alimento> RetornarAlimentos()
    {
        return ctx.Alimentos.Include("Categoria").ToList();
    }
```

Agradeço a ajuda desde já, muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: porque o `body` é um tipo string, e vc está passando uma lista, não vai funcionar mesmo. Teste criar um string com os dados que tem no `List` que vai funcionar

Comment: Sim, se eu atribuir vai funcionar a uma string vai funcionar... mas acontece que eu não tenho como prever quantos produtos vão vir dessa lista... logo não tenho como prever quantos string's criar

Comment: *"logo não tenho como prever quantos string's criar"*, vc só precisa de uma variável, faz um `foreach` na lista e vai adicionando na `string`, ou melhor, um `StringBuilder` e usa só essa variável

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro se dá por você tentar concatenar uma variável do tipo `List<>` com uma string. Você deve montar uma string contendo as informações da lista e depois joga-la na string amigo.

```js
 string alimentos = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
   alimentos += string.Format("Nome do alimento: {0}, Categoria do alimento: {1}{2}", a[i].Nome, a[i].Categoria, Environment.NewLine);
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(alimentos))
   alimentos = "Nenhum alimento encontrado";

try
{
   WebMail.Send(to: email,
                from: "airtonteste@gmail.com"",
                subject: assunto,
  body: alimentos +
        "<p> Agradecemos o contato!</p>"
     );
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "UsuarioCliente");
}
catch
{
   return RedirectToAction("Create", "UsuarioCliente");
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar como resposta pra ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida

Comment: Pronto, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir a biblioteca para serialização em JSON mais usada na arquitetura DotNet, e realizar a serialização da sua lista em uma string, segue um exemplo:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string suaListaSerializada = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(suaLista);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Deu um erro após serializar:  Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
Self referencing loop detected with type 'ProjetoCotacao2.Models.Alimento'. Path '[0].estabelecimento.alimentos'.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'ProjetoCotacao2.Models.Alimento'. Path '[0].estabelecimento.alimentos'.

Erro de Origem: